# Replacing content of div with used time

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know what I did wrong? At first I created a global variable in another HTML file in a script tag with the current time. Now I want to count the time between this document and another document, when it opens. Its a part of a simple 2D game, and this will be a time counter. I tried it like this but it doesn't work.

First HTML part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var elem = document.getElementById('game');
        elem.addEventListener("keydown", KeyPressed );
        start = performance.now();
</script>
```

Second one in the other HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var zeit = performance.now();
        document.getElementById('sc').innerHTML = 'Dauer: ' + ((zeit - start) / 1000) + ' sek.';
</script>
```

Sc means the div box where I want to shwow the time.

Comment: Please see [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can try setting the value of `start` in a cookie in the first file and accessing it through the cookie in the second file. When you switch window the reference to `start` is lost https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie and also some other light reading on window https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window you could also use local storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you create `start` in one [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) and try to access it in another window you lose the reference to `start` in the second html file. One solution is using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the start time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var elem = document.getElementById('game');
        elem.addEventListener("keydown", KeyPressed );
        start = performance.now();
        localStorage.setItem('start', start);
</script>
```

then in the second file get the start time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var zeit = performance.now();
        var start = localStorage.getItem("start");
        document.getElementById('sc').innerHTML = 'Dauer: ' + ((zeit - start) / 1000) + ' sek.';
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks a lot! But now I have the problem, that it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". I thought that innerHTML is available in every browser so I used this instead of innerText?

Comment: i know the problem. the div doesnt exist when I try to replace the value of it. I solved it, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could be out of scope:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

This would imply that the second script tag has no knowledge of `start` have you tried logging `console.log(start)` to check if it is available?

To handle this you may want to add the variable `start` somewhere as a hidden variable that your second script can access or if a redirect happens you may need to pass it as a parameter.

If this isn't correct could you please give a little more detail as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I made the variable start as a gloabale variable, so normally the script can acces to it. I also tried it with console.log but it chrome (my browser) says 'Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined'.        I'm trying to porgram a simple 2D jump and run for school. I failed at collision detection and the score. I want to count the time between opening the game.html and the win.html and display the time on the win.html

Comment: In this case you might want to consider a stand alone js file, this way you could make some methods and call them with the required values, again a relatively simple way of doing this would be a cookie or a hidden input with the value set to the start time.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access a variable from other HTML file